# Spring Security, Login after Registration

Tags: spring, spring-security

In my project , I have 2 modules: one for login and another for registering new user.

If user already exists , my login module which is developed using Spring Security works fine i.e. after login User Id gets stored as `UserPrincipal` into `HttpServletRequest` object.

For registering new user , I make first entry in database and then try to authenticate using Spring Security , I write following code to do it and it works fine.

Snippet:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
authMgr.authenticate(auth);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

The problem is that I am not getting `UserPrincipal` in `HttpServletRequest`.
so after calling `setAuthentication(auth)`, I call `request.getuserprincipal()` and it returns null.

Answer (score 1):

Probably right after the line: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

I would add:
request.getSession().setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());

Otherwise the user won't be in session which is required by Spring Security.

Comment: ❤️ Thank you soo much. I was losing my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line of code, i think this will help you:

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, udetail.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, The code is exactly same except I had to redirect request to get UserPrincipal added in request.  Surprisingly , request.forward was not working though forward dispatcher was added in web.xml for spring filter.